# Работа с матрицами (Си)

Tags: c

Есть следующий код. Нужно сделать так, что бы размер матрицы и промежуток с которого брать числа вводились пользователем.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define predel 100

int i_comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, l, mat[N][N];
    int diag[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    mat[i][j] = rand() % predel;
    printf("Заполняем матрицу случайными числами от 0 до %d:\n", predel);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
            puts("\n\n");
    }
    puts("Отображаем матрицу симметрично по диагонали:\n");
    j = 1;
    l = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            for(; j < N; j++)
                    mat[j][i] = mat[i][j];
            j = ++l;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
            puts("\n\n");
    }
    j = 0;
    l = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            diag[i] = mat[i][j];
            j++;
    }
    qsort(diag, N, sizeof(int), i_comp);
    printf("Минимаьный элемент диагонали:   %d\n", diag[0]);
    printf("Максимальный элемент диагонали: %d\n", diag[N-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Если кому-то интересно, то вот полное условие задания.

Заполнить матрицу А случайными числами.
Отобразить матрицу симметрично относительно главной диагонали.
Найти максимальный и минимальный элемент главной диагонали. Размер матрицы и промежуток случайных чисел задает сам пользователь.

Comment: В чём ваш вопрос? Сделать, чтобы работало? Или вы можете уточнить в чём проблема?

Comment: @Unick вопрос в том, как реализовать ввод размера матрицы и промежутки, с которых рандом будет брать числа в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Boredix почему бы вам было не задать вопрос "как вводить числа с клавиатуры, Си"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь компилятором, который поддерживает стандарт С99 (с С11 могут возникнуть вопросы), то просто вводите две переменные string & colum с клавиатуры, а потом создаете массив: array [string][colum];. Главное: не инициализируйте его во время объявления! В данном случае это не возможно. Можно также использовать ф-цию malloc, если ваш компилятор не поддерживает подобное объявление массива.